# About a sequence of continuous functions

Tags: analysis

Let $\Omega$  a bounded domain in $R^n$ . Let $u_k :  \Omega \rightarrow R$ a sequence of nonnegative continuous functions with $u_{k+1} \geq u_k$. Fix $x \in \partial \Omega$ and supose that $\displaystyle\lim_{y \rightarrow x} u_k(y) = L $ . Define $u(y) : = \displaystyle\lim_k   u_k(y)$and supoose that this function is continuous. Then I have

$$\displaystyle\lim_{y \rightarrow x} u(y) = L  ?$$

I don't know how to prove this. Someone can give me help to prove or disprove this? If this is true, then it will help me to read a part of an article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It need not be true. Consider $\Omega = (0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, and

$$u_k(x) = \begin{cases} (k-1)x &, x < \frac{1}{k} \\ 1-x &, x \geqslant \frac{1}{k}.\end{cases}$$

Then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} u_k(x) = 0$ for all $k$, but $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} u(x) = 1$.